# Extracting single integer in Haskell from list

Tags: haskell

Totally new to Haskell.  Problem- I have a type constructor with a value constructor consisting of 4 components:

```
 TrackPoint :: TP { rpm :: Integer
               , time :: Integer
               , distance :: Float
               , speed :: Float 
               } deriving (Show)
```

I would like to take [TrackPoint] and have it return time, distance and speed anytime the rpm value is below 10,000.  I have tried using guards with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated by this novice.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you provide some example inputs with corresponding outputs?

Answer (score 3):

Simple function:

```
processTrackPoints :: [TrackPoint] -> [(Integer, Float, Float)]
processTrackPoints tps = 
  map (\tp -> (time tp, distance tp, speed tp)) $
  filter (\tp -> rpm tp > 10000) tps
```

Same, but point-free where possible:

```
processTrackPoints :: [TrackPoint] -> [(Integer, Float, Float)]
processTrackPoints = 
  map (\tp -> (time tp, distance tp, speed tp)) .
  filter ((> 10000) . rpm)
```

Using guards:

```
processTrackPoints :: [TrackPoint] -> [(Integer, Float, Float)]
processTrackPoints ((TP rpm time distance speed) : t)
  | rpm > 10000 = (time, distance, speed) : processTrackPoints t
  | otherwise = processTrackPoints t
processTrackPoints _ = []
```

That is all, of course, assuming, that you have the datatype defined correctly like this:

```
data TrackPoint = 
  TP { 
    rpm :: Integer, 
    time :: Integer, 
    distance :: Float, 
    speed :: Float 
  } 
  deriving (Show)
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s easy to do with comprehensions:

```
[ (time, distance, speed)
| TP rpm time distance speed <- trackPoints
, rpm < 10000
]
```

Even easier with `{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}`:

```
[ (time, distance, speed)
| TP{..} <- trackPoints
, rpm < 10000
]
```

The convention for records in Haskell is usually to prefix them to avoid name collisions, e.g., `tpRpm`. It’s also worthwhile to remember that list comprehensions are just sugar for the list monad:

```
timesDistancesAndSpeedsOrSomeBetterName <- do
  TP{..} <- trackPoints
  guard (rpm < 10000)
  return (time, distance, speed)
```